# Ember CLI app inside a Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, rails-engines

I'm making a Rails engine that has an `/admin` route. I'd like to create this admin interface with Ember CLI.

I know rails will automatically precompile any static JS/CSS that live in my engine's `lib` dir, and only load them when the parent application mounts my engine and visits that route. However, I'd like to use Ember CLI to build the admin interface.

What would be a good way to do this? Ideally I'd like to keep Ember CLI builds out of the repo.

Comment: have solved this? I use to develop ember-cli applications as stand-alone projects and use ember-rails gem for ember apps inside a rails projects. As   from Ember2.0 I'd like to introduce ember-cli in my main rails project but without loosing the advantages of add-ons, bower, broccoli etc..

Comment: I wrote a rake task that runs `ember build` and moves the static `dist` into `public/my-engine`, and merges those public static assets with the host app's `public` folder. So, I haven't found a way to avoid the build step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution involved storing a build of the Ember CLI app in the engine.

I wrote a rake task that runs `ember build` and moves the static `dist` into the `public/my-engine` directory, and merges those public static assets with the host app's public folder.

Here's the task for [our particular project](https://github.com/tedconf/front_end_builds):

```
namespace :admin do
  task :build do
    Dir.chdir('admin') do
      sh 'ember build  --environment=production'
    end

    # Copy the dist to public
    FileUtils.rm_r 'public/front_end_builds'
    FileUtils.mv 'admin/dist', 'public/front_end_builds'

    # Move the index out of public
    FileUtils.mv 'public/front_end_builds/index.html', 'app/views/front_end_builds/admin/index.html.erb'
  end
end
```